# How to store application ID credentials safely to be accessed by an application to build sql connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, credentials, password-encryption

I have a windows forms application built on c#. The app connects to a sql server with a windows application ID to operate.
The user will not have access to this App ID credentials. They just connect as a remote application with their own windows ID. And the application's back-end connects with the app ID to the DB.

I need a way to safely store the App ID credentials in the server where I host the tool. The Credentials should be easily updated every now and then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to store secret key of the c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579119/where-to-store-secret-key-of-the-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Is your backend a separate process? You could run this process as a designated user, give this user also SQL server access and use Windows authentication to connect to SQL server

Comment: Or you may be able to utilize Windows Data Protection API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection